# GPS Provider is not triggered - google playservices location api's?

Tags: android, google-maps, location, google-play-services

I am using google play services api to getlast location 
But i have noticed that they are not triggering GPS Provider at all
were as google maps trigger GPS automatically when you are OUTDOOR

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener,
    com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {



private static final int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
FragmentManager myFragmentManager;
static MapFragment myMapFragment;
public static GoogleMap myMap;
LocationClient mLocationClient;



// Milliseconds per second
private static final int MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND = 1000;
// Update frequency in seconds
public static final int UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 5;
// Update frequency in milliseconds
private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL = MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND
        * UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;
// The fastest update frequency, in seconds
private static final int FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS = 1;
// A fast frequency ceiling in milliseconds
private static final long FASTEST_INTERVAL = MILLISECONDS_PER_SECOND
        * FASTEST_INTERVAL_IN_SECONDS;
private static final String TAG = "CheckCurLocation";

// Define an object that holds accuracy and frequency parameters
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
boolean mUpdatesRequested;

SharedPreferences mPrefs;
SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;
Location myCurrentLocation;
Button mLocBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mLocBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.locationBtn);
    mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("SharedPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    // Get a SharedPreferences editor
    mEditor = mPrefs.edit();
    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(MainActivity.this, this, this);
    mUpdatesRequested = false;
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    // Use high accuracy


    myFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    myMapFragment = (MapFragment) myFragmentManager
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
/*  startActivity(new Intent(
            Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));*/



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    mEditor.putBoolean("KEY_UPDATES_ON", mUpdatesRequested);
    mEditor.commit();
    super.onPause();
}

public void getLoction(View v) {
    if (mLocationClient.isConnected()) {

        Log.d(TAG, "Location client connected");
        Location currentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "client connected",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (currentLocation != null) {

            Log.d(TAG, "Location client connected");
            Log.d(TAG, "Lasloc === " + currentLocation);
            drawMap(currentLocation);

        } else {
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(
                    Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
            Log.d(TAG, "location null");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "  location null",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    } else if (mLocationClient.isConnecting()) {

        Log.d(TAG, "client connecting");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "client connecting",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {

        Log.d(TAG, "client not connected");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "client not connected",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    /*
     * Get any previous setting for location updates Gets "false" if an
     * error occurs
     */
    if (mPrefs.contains("KEY_UPDATES_ON")) {
        mUpdatesRequested = mPrefs.getBoolean("KEY_UPDATES_ON", false);

        // Otherwise, turn off location updates
    } else {
        mEditor.putBoolean("KEY_UPDATES_ON", false);
        mEditor.commit();
    }
    /*
     * Location currentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
     * drawMap(mLocationClient.getLastLocation()); }
     */
}

private void drawMap(Location lastLocation) {
    myMap = myMapFragment.getMap();

    if (myMap != null) {
        final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(lastLocation.getLatitude(),
                lastLocation.getLongitude());
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "update google play services"+lastLocation.getLatitude()+","+lastLocation.getLongitude(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
myMap.clear();
        myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        myMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        myMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        myMap.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
        myMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        myMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(new CameraPosition(HAMBURG, 14, 0, 90)));
        myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
        .title("I am here"+lastLocation.getLatitude()+","+lastLocation.getLongitude()).flat(true).rotation(245));

    } else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext()) != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "update google play services",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    /*
     * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects. If the error
     * has a resolution, try sending an Intent to start a Google Play
     * services activity that can resolve error.
     */
    if (result.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
            result.startResolutionForResult(this,
                    CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
            /*
             * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
             * PendingIntent
             */
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            // Log the error
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "update services",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {

    super.onStart();
    mLocationClient.connect();

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {

    super.onStop();
    mLocationClient.disconnect();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // If already requested, start periodic updates


        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        // Set the update interval to 5 seconds
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        // Set the fastest update interval to 1 second
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);

        mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);


    Log.d(TAG, "Location client Connected =========");
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Dis Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (mLocationClient.isConnected()) {
        /*
         * Remove location updates for a listener. The current Activity is
         * the listener, so the argument is "this".
         */

        mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
        // removeLocationUpdates(this);
    }
    /*
     * After disconnect() is called, the client is considered "dead".
     */
    mLocationClient.disconnect();
    Log.d(TAG, "Location client disconnected =========");
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    String msg = "Updated Location: "
            + Double.toString(location.getLatitude()) + ","
            + Double.toString(location.getLongitude());
    Log.d(TAG, "Onlocation changed" + msg);

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

manifest

```
<permission
    android:name="com.example.checkmaps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

enable all the location based settings in phone

issue iam unable to get any GPS based periodic updates in outdoor environments were as google maps get GPS based periodic update
am i missing some thing in location request settings

Answer (score 0):

Possibilities that you are not getting GPS updates are:

1)  try adding another permission in your application manifest file :

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

2) By the way where's your `<meta-data>` code like this:

```
 <meta-data  android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

              <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="YourApiKey" />
```

3) Use only one **LocationListener** either from Android or from google-play-service library,not sure may be it could conflict. If you are using **LocationClient** then don't disconnect from it until you want location updates.

4) You should add this line of Code in your ****drawMap***()* function:

```
myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```